# C#'s operators' order of operation

Tags: c#, c++, operator-precedence

I am porting a C++ utility to C#. When I run the following statement in C++, I get the correct operation. When I run the same statement in C#, however...

[image: omgwtfbbq]

Does anyone know why 'begin++' is executed? The crazy thing is that if I run (i % 2) == 0 with i=0, the Immediate Window returns true.

Comment: Is this even defined behavior in C++?

Comment: If this doesn't persuade you to stop writing code like that I don't know what will.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I think we're seeing 2 steps in C#

Comment: @CodeInChaos: No, it's not defined behavior in C++, since `i++` is both incremented and read between sequence points.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know that reading and incrementing without a sequence point leads to undefined behavior. But I wasn't sure if `=` is a sequence point or not.

Comment: In case you are wondering, the compiler is VC6 w/o dinkumware.

Comment: You get "correct" behaviour entirely by accident in C++; there is no "correct" behaviour in C++. Or, rather, *every behaviour is correct*. In C# there is only *one* correct behaviour, and you're getting it, I assure you. If you expect different behaviour, it is your expectations that are incorrect, so my recommendation is to start expecting the correct behaviour in C#, and stop relying on implementation details in C++.

Comment: @tlg: You mean VC6 from friggin' 1998? Do yourself a favor and update to an actual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Operator precedence is irrelevant in this question. It's evaluation order that causes this behavior.

In C# `i++` is evaluated before `i % 2` since it's on the left side. Thus `i % 2` is false and the right side of the if gets evaluated.

First you use precedence to get the syntax tree:

```
=
  buffer[i++]
  if i % 2
    then temp[end--]
    else temp[begin++]
```

On each node you evaluate the children from left to right. This implies that `i++` is evaluated before `i % 2`.

Eric Lippert has plenty of posts on this, both here on SO, and on his blog:

- [Precedence vs Associativity vs Order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx)
- [Precedence vs order, redux](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/10/precedence-vs-order-redux.aspx)

Personally I'd avoid such code. It's much nicer to split it into multiple expressions, or even use a plain `if` statement instead of `? :`

---

In C++ accessing a variable that was written to without a sequence point in between is undefined behavior. I think `=` is no sequence point, so I guess your expression is undefined in C++ and just happened to work.

Comment: Building on that, you could change it to be `buffer[i] = (i++ % 2) == 0 ? temp[end--] : temp[begin++];`

Comment: @Rob: `buffer[i] = i++` is still undefined behavior due to lack of sequence points.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I think he meant that would fix the problem in C#, although not in C++.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, but why don't you just make your intentions clear?

```c#
if(i % 2 == 0) {
    buffer[i] = temp[end--];
} else {
    buffer[i] = temp[begin++];
}

i++;
```

Comment: I'd even put the i++ after the `if`. And that higher operator precedence means earlier execution is a common myth.

Comment: I think I'd introduce a temp and avoid writing buffer[i++] twice. But yes, this is the right way to handle this. In fact I have no problems writing increments on separate lines, no arguments when done that way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `begin < end` is correct? You will miss one element at the end, if I'm not mistaken.

Here is how I would write it in C++:

```
for (; begin <= end; ++i)
{
    buffer[i] = temp[(i & 1) == 0 ? end-- : begin++];
}
```

But if you think about it, the conditional inside the loop really isn't necessary, because it flip-flops with every iteration. It would be more efficient to simply have two copy operations inside the loop:

```
while (begin < end)
{
    buffer[i++] = temp[end--];
    buffer[i++] = temp[begin++];
}
if (begin == end)
{
    buffer[i++] = temp[end--];
}
```

I changed the loop condition back to `<` and added an `if` in case there is an odd number of elements.